# Why am I unable to access any Microsoft website?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox

I'm using the Windows XP SP2 operating system. My ISP is the Pakistan Telecommunication Company Limited (PTCL).

Whenever I try to access a Microsoft website, the following message appears:

Server not found

Firefox can't find the server at www.microsoft.com.

```
Check the address for typing errors such as ww.example.com instead of www.example.com
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

And, there's a Try Again button at the end.

Other websites are working fine.

What could be the reason?

As far as I know, there're no restrictions on Microsoft websites here in Pakistan.

Comment: If you use a VPN or a proxy, does it work, why are you using SP2 instead of SP3?  If your unable to upgrade to SP3 it will b very difficult to help you.

Comment: Is it possible your place of employment is censoring websites you visit?

Comment: @Anaksunaman it's in my home that I'm using the Internet. And, there's no censoring upon the Microsoft.com.

Comment: Hmm. Well it sounds like a DNS issue, but what that issue is might be pretty broad, especially if other sites are working. At a guess, a virus or malware? I know that some virii e.g. Conficker (a botnet virus) will block Microsoft.com (or at least it did) to prevent security/malware update and detection.